# checking NA values and ignoring them

Tags: python

I have used try - except and it works, but I was wondering if we can perform a similar function with for - if and else.

```
# check for "NA" values, ignore the entries which have them
    # index: DeptTime = 4,Deptdelay = 15, Arrtime = 6, ArrDelay = 14
    for index in flight_data[1:]:
        try:
            x_dept.append(int(index[4]))
            y_dept.append(int(index[15]))
            x_arr.append(int(index[6]))
            y_arr.append(int(index[14])) 
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

For instance, can we do something like this to get the exactly same answer?

```
 # check for "NA" values, ignore the entries which have them
        # index: DeptTime = 4,Deptdelay = 15, Arrtime = 6, ArrDelay = 14
        for index in flight_data[1:]:
            if index[4] =='NA' or index[15] == 'NA' or index[14] =='NA' or index[6] == 'NA':
             pass
             else:
                x_dept.append(int(index[4]))
                y_dept.append(int(index[15]))
                x_arr.append(int(index[6]))
                y_arr.append(int(index[14]))
```

Comment: I know it says java, but the concept holds here.

Comment: Yes, you can do it this way and it will work fine.  For a more general solution, you could say `if not index[4].isdigit()` instead of `if index[4] == 'NA'`, to also catch other cases of non-numeric content.

Comment: Also, your two code samples don't quite behave the same way.  If, say, the first value is an integer and the second one is 'NA', the try/except method will append one value to x_dept and then hit the exception, where the if/else method will not, as it explicitly checks all four values before trying to append.

Comment: So it does work to:    

 `for index in flight_data[1:]:
        if not index[4].isdigit():
            pass
        elif not index[15].isdigit():
            pass
        elif not index[6].isdigit():
            pass
        elif not index[14].isdigit():
            pass
            
        else: 
            x_dept.append(int(index[4]))
            y_dept.append(int(index[15]))
            x_arr.append(int(index[6]))
            y_arr.append(int(index[14]))` 
       
But it just gives wrong value that's all.